# Change PHP array keys to skip every two iterations after two values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Probably best explained with code example.

I have a simple array with normal key order:

```
$array = array(
    '0' => 'Value',
    '1' => 'Value',
    '2' => 'Value',
    '3' => 'Value',
    '4' => 'Value',
);
```

Is there a way to change it so keys come in this order?

```
$array = array(
    '0' => 'Value',
    '1' => 'Value',
    '4' => 'Value',
    '5' => 'Value',
    '8' => 'Value',
);
```

Comment: *skip every two iterations after two values* - Then why `8` is present there? Not clear enough!

Comment: Sorry, `8` was in fact meant to be `9` in this example. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: **Strange**. Till now every one told me **0 is a number and most valuable depending on the position**. @C0dekid.php

Comment: @Sougata is on the point as well, it should start with `0`. Just needed it to start with `1` for my particular case but will edit it for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    'value',
    'value',
    'value',
    'value',
    'value',
    'value',
    'value',
    'value'
);

$newArray = [];
$mustSkip = 1;
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$i] = $value;

    if($mustSkip == 2) {
        $i = $i+3;
        $mustSkip = 1;
    }
    else {
        $i++;
        $mustSkip++;
    }
}
echo "<pre>",print_r($newArray,1),"</pre>";
exit;
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => value
    [2] => value
    [5] => value
    [6] => value
    [9] => value
    [10] => value
    [13] => value
    [14] => value
)
```

Tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
<pre>
$newArray = array();
$i = 1;
foreach ($array as $key => $value)  {
    $newArray[$i] = $value;
    if ($key % 2 && $key) {
        $i += 3;
    } else {
        $i++;
    }
}
var_dump($newArray);
</pre>
```